# NoClassDefFoundError from Xamarin.Forms application in google play pre-launch tests

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play-console

I've built a simple Xamarin.Forms (4.7) application using VS2019 on Windows.  I've tested it locally on emulator and a couple of random physicals I happened to have.  All seems good.  When I submitted the APK to Google Play Store, they run some pre-launch automated tests.  I got 10 crashes from 10 devices with the same exception (below).  I'm not normally an android developer, so this is all new/foreign to me.

Is this something I need to be worried about?  Does this indicate some kind of exception that I should be handling in my code? Or is there a project setting that needs changing? Or is it indicating there is an issue in the 3rd party type: com.zebra.scannercontrol ([Zebra Xamarin Wrapper for Scanner SDK](https://techdocs.zebra.com/dcs/scanners/xamarin-scanner/about/))

Any help would be appreciated.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx, PID: 10114
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat;
    at com.zebra.scannercontrol.BluetoothLEManager.start(BluetoothLEManager.java:148)
    at com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler.handleBTAdapterStateChange(SDKHandler.java:1448)
    at com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler.access$1000(SDKHandler.java:46)
    at com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler$1.onReceive(SDKHandler.java:1288)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1219)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.content.ContextCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 12 more
```